# How to change color of a rectangle element in Enterprise architect Whiteboard diagram

Tags: colors, diagram, enterprise-architect, whiteboard

I am new to EA, and for my high level layered architecture, I just want to draw a whiteboard diagram with few rectangles. I want to change the colour of the rectangles, However, the right click context pop for colour is not changing my rectangle colour. Any inputs on this is soo appreciated...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it. Those elements are created with the help of shape scripts. If you take for example the [rounded rectangle](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Shapescript-Library/blob/master/Whiteboard/roundrect.shapeScript) you see that they don't regard the user color settings. You can either manipulate the shape scripts in the Whiteboard MDG yourself or ask Sparx for a new feature. (If you want to see a change in your lifetime I'd recommend the first.)

Alternatively just draw a Boundary which can be set to Solid which enables color filling.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.. That is something they should add or atleast show an error msg. Tried your suggestion, I can change boundary box colour in component diagram but not in white board diagram. So, guess, I will have to replace my layered diagram completely with boundary element in component diagram.

Comment: Not necessarily. The Whiteboard diagrams have the Whiteboard mode. Open the diagram properties and uncheck `Diagram/Whiteboard Mode`. That's what making the whole diagram wobbly frames only. Send a feature request and demand a fill on whiteboard mode diagrams. It just does not make sense to only have frames here with no fill.